# add rows with a sequence number for a specific position in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a query with two columns: `pos_id` and `pos_count` . I want to add a column `pos_seq` and for each pos_id a number of rows that is equal to the pos_count.

for example:

```
pos_id  pos_count
A           2
B           2
C           1
D           3
```

It means: the position A has two different positions. So I want two rows: one with seq 1 and the other seq 2
So the result has to be:

```
pos_id  pos_count   pos_seq
A          2         1
A          2         2
B          2         1
B          2         2
C          1         1
D          3         1
D          3         2
D          3         3
```

**exception**: sometimes the pos_count is equal to 999. Then I only want 1 row (not 999 for that position)

Comment: Do you want to create a new table with the new column (possibly a bad idea), or do you want to add a column to an existing table (bad idea), or you want the output of a query from the table to have an additional computed column of `pos_seq`?

Comment: I want to output of a query from the table with an additional computed column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood the format of your input data in my original answer.

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to expand your source rows into multiple rows based on the `pos_count` value for each.  Like this:

```
select pos_id, pos_count, pos_seq,
from mytable 
outer apply ( SELECT rownum pos_seq 
              FROM   dual
              CONNECT BY rownum <= pos_count AND pos_count != 999 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a recursive query:

```
with cte (pos_id, pos_count, pos_seq) as
(
  select pos_id, pos_count, 1 as pos_seq from mytable
  union all
  select pos_id, pos_count, pos_seq + 1
  from cte
  where pos_seq < pos_count and pos_count <> 999
)
select *
from cte
order by pos_id, pos_seq;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7ae031df4fd8aee789badf8429c2a1a3